# Different number of yticklabels in different subplots

Tags: matplotlib

I have the following plot:

[image]

The subplots are created as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 3, figsize=(8,10), sharey='col')
```

And after code for populating the bars, I have the following code:

```
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set_xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    ax.set_xticklabels(['50', '10', '0', '50', '10', '0'])
    ax.grid(True, axis='y', color='lightgray', which='both')

handles, labels = axs.flat[-1].get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper left', prop={'size': 9}, bbox_to_anchor=(0.088, 0.97))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

My problem is that the number of yticklabels in the first column of subplots is different compared to the number of yticklabels in the other two columns. I would prefer to have the subplots in other two columns also have as much yticklabels as the subplots in the first column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `set_ylim`, for example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 3, figsize=(8,10), sharey='col')

data = np.random.rand(12,5) * 12

for ind,ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    ax.set_xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    ax.set_xticklabels(['50', '10', '0', '50', '10', '0'])
    ax.set_yticks(list(range(0,14,2)))
    ax.set_yticklabels(list(range(0,14,2)))
    ax.set_ylim(0,14)
    
    dat = data[ind]
    if ind % 3 != 0: dat /= 5
    ax.plot(data[ind])
    ax.grid(True, axis='y', color='lightgray', which='both')
```